# TypeError when autoincrementing column in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following table definition

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = Column(String(256), unique=True)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, id, email, is_admin):
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.is_admin = is_admin
```

When I add a user I only call it with two arguments because I would like the id to be autoincremented and hence not passed by my call:

```
u = User(email=email, is_admin=admin)
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument
```

How do I define a primary_key column without the need to pass it as an argument?

Comment: Just don't set id at all

Comment: I need to refer to this entry from another table. How do I identify this table entry then?

Comment: When you define that column is primary_key (you don't even need to explicitly set `autoincrement`), it will create a sequence and id will be set at database level, which is considered to be the best way to deal with entities

Comment: In the class you have written, you do not need to define the `__init__`, inheriting from `Base` takes care of that for you.

Comment: I did as suggested but now I get the following: admin = User(email, True)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: OK, seems I have to add email=email, is_admin=True

Comment: @SabinaOrazem see my answer below, and yes SQLAlchemy uses keyword arguments for instantiation.

Comment: Maybe you could also add the sentence about removing autoincrement? And removing it from the code. Both suggestions worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need this `__init__` definition, inheriting from `Base` creates one for you, which accepts only keyword arguments, not positional which is causing the issue with missing `id` in your question.

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = Column(String(256), unique=True)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)

u = User(email=email, is_admin=admin)  # OK
```